# ng-select change dropdown arrow using image url

Tags: css, angular, angular-ngselect

I am trying to use an image in assets folder to change the ng-select dropdown arrow.

there are references to make use of font-awesome like below - which is working

```
.ng-select .ng-arrow-wrapper .ng-arrow {
    display: none;
}

.ng-select span.ng-arrow-wrapper:before {
    content: "\f0ab";
    display: inline-block;
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-rendering: auto;
}
```

However, I am trying something like below to achieve it:

```
.ng-select ::ng-deep .ng-arrow {
  display: none;
}
.ng-select ::ng-deep .ng-arrow-wrapper {
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  background-image: url('../assets/arrowhead-down.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-right: 12px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.ng-select-opened ::ng-deep .ng-arrow-wrapper {
  background-image: url('../assets/arrowhead-down.svg');
}
```

However, this isn't rendering the assets image. Appreciate any inputs.

[image: This is the caret I am using for dropdown arrow]

^^ this is the image caret I am using for dropdown arrow

The problem for me here is not the usage of assets. I am trying to get the background image url work (it could be any url). The reason being I am using angular elements where one of the element will be using this ng-select. Since, these elements will be part of a javascript import, I cannot have it as part of assets. So, I am trying to make use of background image from our hosted CDN. However, I am unable to get the image to show up in the dropdown

Thanks,
Ani

Answer (score 4):

I understand what the OP wanted to do here is the answer - I tried it and it works.

```
.ng-select .ng-arrow-wrapper .ng-arrow {
  border-color: none !important;
  border-style: none !important;
  border-width: 0 !important;
}
.ng-select .ng-arrow-wrapper {
  background-image: url('/assets/img/arrowhead-down.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 14px 14px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}
```

originally I had posted a different answer but I understood what the issue was - however, the assets path should always be preceded by a / at the root.  You did not need to use ng-deep.

Comment: for some reason it doesn't work even after removing .. Here is the slackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cf81mj?file=src/app/app.component.css that I am trying

Comment: This is not true. If you have files in a non-component scoped scss folder at the project root, for example, you must link directly to the file in assets using .., etc.

Comment: climowski this is only correct for angular 10 and only as a work around.  as demonstrated directly on the image I posted - it is in fact working and showing up.  I think dude has some browser cache problems - but I shouldn't be down voted for that.  you're answer however should be downvoted - because nowhere on angular.io does it state this only on a single GitHub instance.  https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/18013

Comment: @chri burd Do you have a working stackblitz that I could refer to? The slackblitz I am working on is https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cf81mj?file=src/app/app.component.css (This is using css and I cleared the cache to test it, it doesn't work either). Updated original question with the image I am expecting.

Comment: Sure, will definitely do. However, the problem for me here is not the usage of assets. I am trying to get the background image url work (it could be any url). The reason being I am using angular elements where one of the element will be using this ng-select. Since, these elements will be part of a javascript import, I cannot have it as part of assets. So, I am trying to make use of background image from our hosted CDN. However, I am unable to get the image to show up in the dropdown.

Comment: @chrisburd did you get a chance to get it work?

Comment: @chrisburd I have tried the provided CSS but it didn't work for me. Please take a look here --> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cf81mj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css Can you share your working stackblitz that I can refer to?

Answer (score 1):

I changed arrow icon with icon font and add rotation animation on close/open

```
.ng-select {
     .ng-arrow {
         font-family: "icomoon" !important;
         border-color: inherit !important;
         border-width: 0 !important;
         font-size: 16px;
         top: 0 !important;
         left: -3px;
         color: inherit;
         text-align: center;
         transform: rotate(0deg);
         transform-origin: 8px 12px;
         transition: transform 0.2s ease;
         &:before {
             content: "\e60f";
         }
   }

   &.ng-select-opened {
       .ng-arrow {
           transform: rotate(180deg);
       }
   }
}
```